# Falha ao tentar registrar um package criado no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo um package para o Laravel 5.1 e de cara já identifiquei um problema que não consegui encontrar a solução.

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'MyNamespace\MyApp\MyAppServiceProvider' not found
```

Porém, não funciona de jeito nenhum, me código.

composer.json

```
...
"psr-4": {
    "MyNamespace\\MyApp\\": "vendor/mynamespace/myapp/src/"
}
...
```

vendor/mynamespace/myapp/src/MyAppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\MyApp;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyAppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            require __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function register()
     {
         //
     }
}
```

E por fim, eu tento registrar o meu ServiceProvider, mas...

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    MyNamespace\MyApp\MyAppServiceProvider::class

],
```

Mas não rolou, apresenta o erro citado no início da postagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vendor -> Intocavel

Muito provável que você esqueceu de dizer ao composer pra reindexar os namespaces:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Blz, referente ao `composer dump-autoload` ele foi executado, porém, o erro persistiu. Modifiquei a estrutura - tirei do vendor - e tudo fluiu de acordo. Obrigado!!!